# android extract style not picking up lots of attributes

Tags: android, eclipse

I have something like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/answer1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/answer1" />
```

and I want to extract the layout width, height, and centerHorizontal to `styles.xml`. When I hit  Refactor -> Extract Style I don't get any of these as an option, but if I enter for example clickable="false" it does show up. Is this by design?